# Translating dynamic strings

Tags: translation, localization

In my form I have a dropdown. I'm getting the values and labels of the dropdown dynamically from SugarCRM via it's rest API.

I would need to translate these strings.

I tried to pass the dynamic string into the I18n localizaton function and translating the "Married" string using CodestylingLocalization plugin:

```
<?php __('Married','ja')?>
<option label="<?php echo esc_html(__($field['value'],'ja')); ?>"
                                value="<?php echo esc_attr(__($field['name'],'ja')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html(__($field['value']),'ja'); ?></option>
```

But that didn't work. Is there a way to translate the dynamic strings using I18n?

Comment: This _should_ work, are you sure your translation is being correctly loaded and definitely contains that exact string?

Comment: Yes, to confirm I just tried `echo __('Married','ja')`, which displays the translated string, and `echo $field['value'] == 'Married' ? 'true' : 'false'`, which displays true.

Comment: But `__($field['value'],'ja')` doesn't? All in same place/file? Hm, this doesn't make technical sense...